# Subspace containing $(f(x_{1}) -t_{1}, \ldots, f(x_{n}) -t_{n})$ for $f \in \mathcal{F}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a $m-$dimensional vector space of real-valued
>   functions $f: \mathcal{X} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$. Let $n=m+2$.
>
> Take any set of $n$ points $(x_{1},t_{1}), \ldots, (x_{n},t_{n})$.
>   Show that: \begin{align} \left\{\left(f(x_{1}) -
>  t_{1},\ldots,f(x_{n})-t_{n} \right):  f \in \mathcal{F}\right\}
>  \end{align} is contained within an $n-1$ dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

It makes sense to me that the vector $\left(f(x_{1}),\ldots,f(x_{n}) \right)'$ for $f$ varying over $\mathcal{F}$ spans a $n-2$ dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. What I do not understand is how subtracting a fixed vector $t \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ would ever allow the vector to span a $n-1$ dimensional subspace as $f$ varies over $\mathcal{F}$. Can anyone offer a simple explanation/proof?

**Further background:** This appears in Lemma 2.6.15 in Van der Vaart and Wellner (1996) *Weak Convergence and Empirical Processes*, although absolutely no knowledge of empirical process theory should be needed to solve this.

Comment: What's the meaning of the $'$ in $\left(f(x_{1}) -
 t_{1},\ldots,f(x_{n})-t_{n} \right)'$?

Comment: What does the prime mean?  More broadly, every real $n-$vector is contained in a $1$ dimensional subspace, so what are you asking?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos the prime is just the transpose (usually I like to keep my vectors as column vectors, so I included it automatically without even thinking). I have removed it to avoid confusion.

Comment: @lulu I am not sure what you are asking. My question is how the vector $(f(x_{1}) - t_{1}, \ldots,f(x_{n})-t_{n})$ could ever actually span a $n-1$ dimensional subspace as $f$ varies over $\mathcal{F}$, since $\mathcal{F}$ is a $n-2$ dimensional vector space of real-valued functions.

Comment: You've just written a single vector!  It obviously does not span an $n-1$ dimensional subspace, it spans (at most) a $1$ dimensional subspace.  Did you mean to say that ALL the vectors of that form lie in a single such subspace?

Comment: Assuming you meant to speak of all the vectors of that form (where the $x_i$ are fixed but the $f$ vary throughout $\mathscr F$), as opposed to just a single vector, then I'd argue that the vectors $(f(x_1),\cdots , f(x_n))$ span a space  $V$ of dimension at most $m=n-2$.  Your vectors are contained in the space generated by $V$ and the vector $\vec t=(t_1,\cdots, t_n)$.  That space has dimension at most $n-1$.

Comment: @lulu I think I understand the confusion  ($(f(x_{1})-t_{1},\ldots, f(x_{n})-t_{n}), f \in \mathcal{F}$, was to be understood to mean $\{(f(x_{1})-t_{1}, f(x_{n})-t_{n})): f \in \mathcal{F}\}$). I have edited the question for clarity.

Comment: Fair enough.  That's what I had guessed you meant, and my comment applies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We denote the given set by
$$
      S
  :=  \{ (f(x_1) - t_1, \dotsc, f(x_n) - t_n) \mid f \in \mathcal{F} \}.
$$
The set
$$
      U
  :=  \{ (f(x_1), \dotsc, f(x_n)) \mid f \in \mathcal{F} \}
$$
is a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is at most $m$-dimensional, since it is the image of the linear map
$$
          \mathcal{F}
  \to     \mathbb{R}^n,
  \quad   f
  \mapsto ( f(x_1), \dotsc, f(x_n) ),
$$
with $\mathcal{F}$ being $m$-dimensional.
It follows that $S$ is contained in the linear subspace
\begin{align*}
      U'
  &:= U + \langle (t_1, \dotsc, t_n) \rangle  \\
  &=  \{ u + \lambda (t_1, \dotsc, t_n) \mid u \in U, \lambda \in \mathbb{R} \} \\
  &=  \{ ( f(x_1) - \lambda t_1, \dotsc, f(x_n) - \lambda t_n ) \mid f \in \mathcal{F}, \lambda \in \mathbb{R} \},
\end{align*}
which is at most $(m+1)$-dimensional, with $m+1 = n-1$.